# Api Maps Offline

Tags: android, google-maps

Boa noite pessoal, tudo bem?
Gostaria de saber se teria como meu aplicativo abrir o mapa quando o usuário estiver sem internet ?

Answer (score 3):

Olá! Sim, tem como fazer usando o maps api, criando seus próprios tiles e usando o TileProvider para manipulá-los. 
Mas o próprio Google não encoraja muito a fazer isto em seus termos de serviço. *"No caching or storage."*

Uma solução open source é utilizar o OpenStreetMaps com tiles de mapa. 
Aqui tem as ferramentas para usar o OSM no Android:
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid

E aqui a ferramenta para você baixar os tiles: 
http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

É isto. ;)